# Can I use same z3 context to solve independent problems?

Tags: z3

I am using z3 as the underlying constraint solver in my application through its C++ interface. I declare an z3 context as member of a class which is used to solve many independent constraint sets.

Here is the thing: I declare the z3 'solver' when solving a constraint set but the z3 'context' is the same one during the solving of many independent problems.
I'm not sure whether it's correct to use the same z3 context during solving of independent problems. BTW my program does what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using separate solvers should be safe as long as all the constraints for each check are asserted into that solver. Note that the context is not thread safe however, so running those solvers in parallel may cause problems if they use the same context.

Comment: Thanks for your superb answer!

Comment: In this regard is is safe to summarize a context as merely the underlying location expressions et. al. are stored? And that it's the solver that will modify the context with new information and actually contain state? (And if so, if I create a solver twice for the same context, although the first solver's state will be lost, the same intermediate expression results will be in the context and so the second solver will be somewhat incremental?)

Comment: That's right, the context contains some state, e.g., symbols, asts/expressions are all managed by the context. In that respect, the context is indeed a little bit incremental (e.g., existing expressions stay there until their reference count goes to zero), but it's not necessarily easy to exploit that to gain any advantage. In fact, some users throw away the context and create a new one from time to time because that happens to work better (in time and memory).

Comment: I am using the same context but different solvers to solve different problems and I experienced extra delay in checking. In other words, using the same context is slower than using different contexts although the result is the same. Is this expected?

Comment: That depends on what those problems/solvers contain and on what you mean by "extra delay". A little bit of overhead is indeed expected.